# Grep the output string of grep command

Tags: linux, bash

I want to `grep` an Id from log based on a error "MyOwnError" then use the same Id to get the whole line of wherever the Id present throughout the log.

Eg:

suppose theres a file `File1`:

```
animal:Dogs hate the animal:catsF and no-one else
animal:catsF hate the animal:fish
animal:catsF also hate animal:humans
```

and my search string is 'Dogs'

```
grep 'Dogs' File1 | grep -o 'animal:.*F'
```

this will give me `animal:catsF`, and now I want to `grep` the 'catsF' for the same file `File1`.

I tried `xargs` but it picked the filenames instead of the args.

```
grep 'Dogs' File1 | grep -o 'animal:.*F' | xargs grep File1
```

Please correct this command or provide the right one.

Comment: How about using command substitution `$()`?

Comment: Can it be other commands like `sed`, `awk`, et al., or does it have to be `grep`? Why?

Comment: Is your search string `Dog` or `Dogs`? You have `catsF` in your example but then say that you want to get `cats1`. Where did the `1` come from? Please [edit] your question and make sure it is correct.

Comment: made the changes, sorry i was using cats1 as the string before catsF, but as @choroba pointed out that *1 is a regex.

Comment: @RudiC yes it can be anything, i just want a command to make thing easier for me while getting specific logs

Comment: Your match of `'animal:*F'` will be greedy, matching the entire line up to catsF.

Answer (score 5):

The command would return the first line up to `F` because it starts with `animal:`. To only get one word, you can specify there's no space between the `animal:` and the `F`:

```
grep 'Dogs' File1 | grep -o 'animal:[^ ]*F'
```

To list all the lines containing that keyword, pipe the output to `grep` again, using `-f-` to read the pattern from the standard input (i.e. the pipe):

```
| grep -Ff- File1
```

I also used `-F`, i.e. "use fixed strings", because I don't think the lines contain regular expressions.

Comment: I used 1 as an example to substring the o/p, the idea of the question to get the output string that is Cats and use the cat as a search string for different grep command.

Comment: With regular expressions, every detail matters. Ask a new question if this answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: My bad @choroba *1 can be regex skipped my mind, please look at the question now its correctly explained now.

Comment: Changing the question in a way that makes the answers invalid is not recommended. Ask a new question as I have already written. Also, `animal:.*F` can still match the phrase `animal:Dogs hate the animal:catsF` - `F` and `1` are not treated differently in regexes.

Comment: To use xargs instead of the suggested `| grep -Ff- File1`:

`| xargs -J % grep "%" File1` or `| xargs -J % grep "^%" File1`